# JSON Ajax isn't returning as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making a simple ajax call as the following;

```
var getPrevious = function(){
    console.log('ajaxing');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'http://'+DOMAIN+'/previous', 
        success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
}
```

Whenever I run this function it's not returning success. What am I doing wrong; here's the url I'm trying to get the json data from; http://107.174.82.43:3001/previous

I'm new to making calls using `$.ajax` but it seems pretty straight forward, although I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: likely your browser is blocking it with cors - check your devtools.

Comment: @DanielA.White oh, yeah a No A-C-A-O, any quick way to solve this? It's making the request from the same domain but the only thing that's changed is the port.

Comment: Downlaod CORS extension for chrome and enable it

Comment: @AllJs but I don't want people to have to download that too if they visist my site.

Comment: the service is going to have to enable cors to allow your request.

Comment: @DanielA.White I use koa, how do I enable cors?

Comment: https://github.com/koajs/cors

Comment: @DanielA.White I tried that a few moments ago, but the problem would still remain and other routes wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: @MartijnEbbens that is beyond my skills and sounds like a new question...

Comment: @DanielA.White reinstalled it and it works now, thanks

Comment: @MartijnEbbens when you deploy your application online, make sure your server is configured to handle cors. If you are using NodeJS for instance, you can use the `cors` module from npm. Your users won't need to install anything. This is just for development purpose

Answer (score 0):

To debug it, use `error` option

```
var getPrevious = function(){
    console.log('ajaxing');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'http://'+DOMAIN+'/previous', 
        success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(err){
           console.error(err);
        }
    });
}
```

If you are running your app on a different from provided domain/port host, than you will face CORS issue. Your should host your js app either on same domain as your back api, or add js app domain to back-end whitelist.